# Unable to read memory in Windows, not in MacOs. Acces violation reading location

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, openframeworks

I've been working on an application in c++. 
I'm trying to create multiple objects from the same class. In Xcode this all works perfectly. But in Visual Studio I keep getting errors. When trying to debug I get an "acces violation reading location 0x00000008", and I get a few errors saying "Unable to read memory".

So i get that the issue is that I'm trying to call this class to an object twice, because a class being called from that first class, is the one saying it can't read the memory.

But why is this an issue on Windows and not on MacOS. I have transferred all my stuff to the windows computer and now this is an issue. I don't really think it'll be something thats specifically wrong in the class. The class that gives the issues is as following:

```
class AbstractByteSink
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractByteSink()
    {
    }
    virtual std::size_t writeByte(uint8_t data) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t writeByte(const uint8_t* buffer, std::size_t size) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t writeByte(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t writeByte(const std::string& buffer) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t writeByte(const AbstractByteSource& buffer) = 0;

};
```

If anyone can tell me why this is a problem on Windows, and how I could possibly fix this, you will be thanked.

Comment: *"acces violation reading location 0x00000008"* means that you probably do `ptr->member` where `ptr` is a null pointer and `member` is at offset 8 in the object. The code you have shown gives no indication of where that might happen.

Comment: The problem is not in the code presented. Use your debugger to find the line of your code that is the problem. Walk up the callstack when the debugger breaks.

Comment: I know which line is the problem. I'm trying to create 2 objects from 1 class. When i only create 1 there are no problems. On my mac i can create 2 objects and make it work without a problem. The callstack throws an error at a certain line right after the thing where i believe it goes wrong

Comment: oh i found the line in the callstack wich is:
006DA6E2 mov edx,dword ptr [eax+8]

Comment: Go up the callstack to your code.